# Allow single example.domain site from the list of blocked .domain referrers

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess file I have the following code that blocks certain domains/referrers as I got massive amount of spam from these domains recently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.(a1|a2|a3|a4)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

Options -Indexes
```

But I would like to allow google.a1, google.a2 etc referrers from the list of blocked referres. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition for `google`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \.(a1|a2|a3|a4)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working fine. Should I use RewriteRule ^ - [F] instead of RewriteRule .* - [F]?

Comment: Yes both mean same thing but `^` is slightly more efficient than `.*`